# Piecewise function and maximum/min

Tags: functions

$f$ is given by

$$f(x) = \begin{cases} 
x^2 \cdot \sin(x) & \text{if }x\geq0\\
1/x&\text{if } x < 0
\end{cases}
$$

and if we look at the interval $[1,2]$

Given the above, how can we use the extreme value theorem to decide which of the following must be true;

$f$ has both a maximum and a minimum in the given interval.

or

$f$ has a maximum but not a minimum in the interval.

I only think we need to use the extreme value theorem... haven't solved this kind of problem before.

Comment: $f$ does not seem to be continues at $0$. This is something you need to take into account, I think.

Comment: @nullgeppetto: Ah, but $0$ is not in the interval $[1,2].$

Comment: Ok, my fault, I saw $[-1,2]$ because it basically makes more sense... But now you have the answer below. :)

Answer (score 2):

On the interval $[1, 2]$, the function $f$ is simply equal to $x^2\sin (x)$, so it is continuous on $[1,2]$ and $f$ has both a maximum and a minimum on the interval.

Comment: Hi. If the interval changes to [-1,2], what does the answer then become? Now it is no longer continuous, right?

Comment: @Jonathan Correct. And then $f$ has no minimum, since $\lim_{x\to 0^-} f(x) = -\infty$